# C# Winform - ToolStripMenuItem "Checked" property not properly reflected on UI

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a C# windows form application in which I implement a `TabControl` object along with a `MenuStrip`. Some of the ToolStripMenuItems' CheckStates are specific to each individual tab.  The tabs are dynamically generated in runtime. I would like to be able to load/set the appropriate `CheckState` of the ToolStripMenuItems each time the user switches to a new tab.

In my code, I have a `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler on the `TabControl` set up to appropriately toggle the CheckStates of the ToolStripMenuItems. When I debug, the event handler is firing as expected and the runtime values of the Menu items' CheckStates change to "Checked" or "Unchecked" exactly as they should. However, the menu items on the Windows form never appear as checked.  The function is as follows:

```
public void Update_Real_Checkstates_on_Tab_Change(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //if a config has not yet been loaded on this tab, return
    if (G_Tab.Active_CFG_Names[G_Tab.myTabCtrl.SelectedIndex] == "") return;  

    //uncheck all the items
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in this.selectCRCTypeToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems) item.Checked = false;

    // "load in" checks from the appropriate place where they are stored
    int j = 0;
    foreach(ToolStripMenuItem item in this.selectCRCTypeToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems)
    {
        item.Checked = G_Tab.old_checkstates[G_Tab.myTabCtrl.SelectedIndex].states[j];
        j++;
    }
}
```

`TabMgr` constructor where event handler is added:
Note: `G_Tab` is an instance of this class

```
public class TabMgr : Template_Editor   //Template_Editor is the base class/Title of the application
{  
    /*
        irrelevant declarations
    */

    public TabMgr(Form myform)
    {
        //Create a reference to the TabControl on the form inside the TabMgr Class instance G_Tab
        TabControl buff = myform.Controls.Find("tabControl1", true).FirstOrDefault() as TabControl;
        myTabCtrl = buff;

        /* 
            More stuff initialized that's not relevant 
        */ 

        //add event handler to TabControl, The event handler is a member function of Base Class Template Editor
        myTabCtrl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(Update_Real_Checkstates_on_Tab_Change); 

        //initialize all the checkstate arrays 
        for (int i = 0; i < old_checkstates.Length; i++) old_checkstates[i].states = new bool[4];  

    }//TabMgr

//More functions implemented here that are not relevant to this post        

}//Public Class TabMgr
```

I have spent multiple days attempting solutions and searching for answers elsewhere, but every example I see seems to be as simple as what I've done here.  There doesn't seem to be anything to it, but clearly I'm missing something here.  Does anyone know of anything that would prevent the UI from properly reflecting the "Checked" and/or "CheckSate" values of these ToolStripMenuItems? I think that somehow the values that are changing are not referencing the actual object but I don't know how to make certain of that. I have tried setting the modifiers of the ToolStripMenuItems to `protected` or `public` in the designer and that hasn't helped any.

Thank you in advance!

Additional Info:
The function `Update_Real_Checkstates_on_Tab_Change` above is a member of the base class `Template_Editor`. `G_Tab` is an instance of class `TabMgr` inherits from the base class.. The `MenuStrip` is a member of the base class.

Edit: I've added code to show the the `TabMgr` Constructor where `G_Tab` is initialized

Comment: From your prose I don't fully grasp what you're doing in the code you haven't shown, but this smacks of confusing two separate form instances.

Comment: Need to see more code...possibly where you generate and wire up everything.

Comment: As requested I've added the code where G_Tab is initialized as an instance of TabMgr, which includes adding the event handler to the tab control

Comment: Are you replacing the current TabControl with `myTabCtrl = buff;`?  Only add an event handler once.  Your code looks like it could potentially be adding it multiple times.

Comment: The TabMgr constructor is only called once in Form_Load(), so I don't think its possible that the event handler could be added multiple times, but i'll put a breakpoint and check.   `myTabCtrl` is previously uninitialized, just null `TabControl` variable declared here in the constructor that should only be getting called once.